# ZF2 form on post losing ID

Tags: zend-framework2

I cant pass the ID from the view (or from somewhere else). This is the url:

http://zend2.com/users/user-manager/edit/6

The controller :

```
    public function editAction()
{
    if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        $post = $this->request->getPost();
        echo $post->user_id; exit;
        $userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
        $user = $userTable->getUser($post->id);
        $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserEditForm');
        $form->bind($user);
        $form->setData($post);
        $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable')->saveUser($user);
    }

    $userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
    $user = $userTable->getUser($this->params()->fromRoute('id'));
    $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserEditForm');

    $form->bind($user);

    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $form,
        'user_id' => $this->params()->fromRoute('id')
    ));
    return $viewModel;

}
```

And the view:

```
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,
    array('controller' => 'users_manager', 'action' => 'edit')));
    $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
```

What is the proper way to pass the ID ? I know that i dont pass the ID in the view but i am not even sure that this is right.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,
array('controller' => 'users_manager', 'action' => 'edit'),null, true));
```

The 4th parameter for $this->url is "$reuseMatchedParameters", it speaks for itself.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is :

```
$options = ['Query' => ['id' => 12]];
echo $this->url('controller' => 'users_manager', 'action' => 'edit', $options);
```